# update using cursor

Tags: sql-server

hope all you are fine. i have some problem  in sql server query.

i want to update recorde in a table which have 534,000 rows. if i create a while loop for update all record then it takes time.

then i should create a cursor for update record. after this i create a cursor for update using Fetch. this cursor complete updating process quickly in 10,000 rows but when i use table which have more than 30,000 rows it takes 5 minuts to execute Query. i don't know what is the problem.

its my code

```
DECLARE @RNo INT --Declaring the Variable @id
DECLARE @id INT --Declaring the Variable @id
set @RNo=1

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR -- Declaring the Cursor
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR --Assigning the cursor
FOR
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable  --Query related to Cursor
for update of Col2

OPEN @MyCursor -- Opening the Created cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor --Retrieving the record one by one
INTO @id --Assigning the value in declared Variable
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN

        update MyTable
        set Col2=@RNo
         where current of @MyCursor

        set @RNo=@rno+1
        print @id
FETCH NEXT
    FROM @MyCursor INTO @id
END
CLOSE @MyCursor -- Closing the Cursor
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor -- Deallocating the Cursor Memory
```

Note: My Query execute with correct data but problem is it takes 5 minuts i only want to execute this query within 10 seconds.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: **GET RID of the cursor!** That's your problem.... **RBAR** processing - **row-by-agonizing-row**. Fine in C#, horribly bad in SQL..... It's not needed at all, and it's just a unnecessary slowdown..... just a single `UPDATE` statement would work, I believe...

Answer (score 3):

A SQL Server expert once told me, if you need to use cursors, ALWAYS make sure you use a LOCAL STATIC cursor.  That aside, this query will update your data in one shot.

```
;WITH TMP AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) RN
  FROM MyTable
)
UPDATE TMP SET Col2 = RN;
```

I have arbitrarily chosen to produce the Row Numbering based on `ORDER BY Col1`, which you can tweak.  Your cursor did not have an `ORDER BY` clause so it would have been pseudo-random anyway.

Comment: yes you are right but i dont want to use row_number. @RNo+1 is just an example. 
My Question is simple that
"If we Update millions of record with cursor then how its possible to update over data in one shot.
for example if we use while loop and under while loop we want to update millions of record then how its possible quickly. "
hope you understand thanks

Comment: ok now i will ask my question with steps. 
Step 1 if you have a table that have 5430000 Rows.
Step 2 table have columns Col1 int, Col2 Varchar, Col3 Varchar
setp 3 i want to update col3 row by row using fetch while loop. 
Fetch While loop is must.

Comment: @LoveTest, maybe if you posted what you are actually trying to achieve, then you'll get some better ideas on how to achieve it. You might find that actually, fetch while loop **isn't** a must.

Comment: but believe me while loop is must for many queries. one of like this